# how to get latitude and longitude from google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I have a requirement.It is whenever user clicks on a button(after giving a street address) the latitude and longitude should be displayed in a alert box.I am trying this code,But it is not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#btn").click(function()
        {
            var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'miami, us'}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    alert("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert("Something got wrong " + status);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="search for miami coordinates" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to request an API key to use google maps.

```
util.js:228 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Add some descriptions to the link plz.

Answer (score 0):

it would be nice to hear **what exactly** is not working.

I see that you don't **NOT** have a [key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for the API usage at least in the snippet. As far as I know is it mandatory. Furthermore you don't have a callback given in the maps url. This is what google gives in the [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map):

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```